# Directory list program not opening correctly

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, dirent.h

Here is the code (for the whole project)

```
File: directoryReader.cpp
//
//  directoryReader.cpp
//  appBetaServer
//
//  Created by Ethan Laur on 3/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ethan Laur. All rights reserved.
//
#include "directoryReader.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
directoryReader::directoryReader()
{
    dir = NULL;
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "directoryReader spawned with no args!");
}
directoryReader::directoryReader(char *d)
{
    dir = NULL;
    setFileMode(S_IFREG);
    setDirectory(d);
}
directoryReader::directoryReader(char *d, mode_t m)
{
    dir = NULL;
    setFileMode(m);
    setDirectory(d);
}
void directoryReader::setDirectory(char * newDir)
{
    strcpy(dirName, newDir);
    if (dir != NULL) closedir(dir);
    dir = NULL;
    reset();
}
void directoryReader::setFileMode(mode_t mode)
{
    fileMode = mode;
}
void directoryReader::reset()
{
    if (dir != NULL) closedir(dir);
    dir = opendir(dirName);
}
char * directoryReader::getNext()
{
    struct stat st;
    char        buf[1024];
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening %s! Will try again\n", dirName);
        setDirectory(strdup(dirName));
        if (dir == NULL)
        {
            printf("\tCould not! FAILED!\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", dirName, ent->d_name);
        if (strstr(buf, "/.") == buf + (strlen(buf) - 1))
        continue;
        if (strstr(buf, "/..") == buf + (strlen(buf) - 2))
        continue;
        stat(buf, &st);
        if (st.st_mode & fileMode)
        return strdup(buf);
    }
    return NULL;
}
File: directoryReader.h
//
//  directoryReader.h
//  appBetaServer
//
//  Created by Ethan Laur on 3/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ethan Laur. All rights reserved.
//
#ifndef __appBetaServer__directoryReader__
#define __appBetaServer__directoryReader__
#include "dirent.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
class directoryReader
{
    protected:
    DIR           *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    mode_t         fileMode;
    char           dirName[1024];
    public:
    directoryReader();
    directoryReader(char *);
    directoryReader(char *, mode_t);
    void setDirectory(char *);
    void setFileMode(mode_t);
    void reset();
    char *getNext();
    };
    #endif /* defined(__appBetaServer__directoryReader__) */
File: main.cpp
//
//  main.cpp
//  fdup
//
//  Created by Ethan Laur on 5/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ethan Laur. All rights reserved.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "directoryReader.h"
char goodpath(char *p)
{
    if (*(p + strlen(p) - 1) == '.')
    return 0;
    return 1;
}
void p_getfiles(char *basepath, FILE *f, char *filename) //filename is to ignore
{
    directoryReader *dirr = new directoryReader(basepath, S_IFREG | S_IFDIR);
    char *tmppath = NULL;
    struct stat st;
    while ((tmppath = dirr->getNext()) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(tmppath, filename) == 0)
        continue;
        if (goodpath(tmppath))
        {
            stat(tmppath, &st);
            if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
            {
                if (strcmp(tmppath, filename) == 0)
                printf("uh oh...\n");
                p_getfiles(tmppath, f, filename);
            }
            else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode));
            //fprintf(f, "%s\n", tmppath);
        }
        free(tmppath);
    }
    delete dirr;
}
void getfiles(char *basepath, char *filename)
{
    FILE *f;// = fopen(filename, "w");
    p_getfiles(basepath, f, filename);
    //fflush(f);
    //fclose(f);
}
int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    getfiles(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

The issue is in directoryReader::getNext() or in p_getfiles(char *, FILE *, char *).

What happens, is this (output);

```
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/83! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/84! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/85! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/86! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/87! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/88! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/89! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8a! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8b! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8c! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8d! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8e! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/8f! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/90! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/91! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/92! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/93! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/94! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/95! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/96! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/97! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/98! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/99! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9a! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9b! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9c! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9d! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9e! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/9f! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a1! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a4! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a7! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/a9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/aa! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b1! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/b9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ba! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/bb! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/bc! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/bd! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/be! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/bf! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c1! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c4! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c7! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/c9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ca! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/cb! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/cc! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/cd! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ce! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/cf! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d1! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d4! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d7! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/d9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/da! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/db! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/dc! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/dd! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/de! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e4! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e7! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/e9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ea! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/eb! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ec! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ed! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ee! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ef! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f1! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f2! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f3! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f4! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f5! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f6! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f7! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f8! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/f9! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/fc! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/fd! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/fe! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/ff! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.DocumentRevisions-V100/staging! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.fseventsd! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.Spotlight-V100! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.Trashes! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //.vol! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //Applications! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //bin! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //cores! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //dev! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //efi! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //etc! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //home! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //Library! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //net! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //Network! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //opt! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //private! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //sbin! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //System! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //tmp! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //Users! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //usr! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //usr0! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //var! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
Error opening //Volumes! Will try again
Could not! FAILED!
```

Now, I don't know much about why this isn't working, though I do know it isn't because of the "//" at the beginning.

If anybody could help me diagnose (at least) or fix this problem, that would be great. If I am missing any information, please leave a comment and I will make edits.

Edit 1: Arguments passed are / and blarg (blarg since the file is never written to nor opened)

Comment: What arguments did you use to run the program that produced the above output?

Comment: I passed / and blarg (since it isn't writing the file anyways). (should recursively list all files on the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the line:

```
      sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", dirName, ent->d_name);
```

to

```
   if (strcmp(dirname, "/") == 0 )
   {
      sprintf(buf, "/%s", ent->d_name);
   }
   else
   {
      sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", dirName, ent->d_name);
   }
```

That made a difference in my testing.

Also,

```
    if (strcmp(tmppath, filename) == 0)
    continue;
```

will result in a memory leak. I would change that to:

```
    if (strcmp(tmppath, filename) == 0)
    {
      free(tmppath);
      continue;
    }
```

Everything else looks good to me.

**Update**

It will be good to have a destructor of `directoryReader` that will close the open directory.

```
directoryReader::~directoryReader()
{
   if (dir != NULL) closedir(dir);
}
```

Also, `p_getfiles` can be reorganized so that:

1. You open a directory, gather all the files and sub-directories of the directory, close the directory, and then process the files and subdirectories. That way, you don't have to worry about too many open directories.
2. You can create an instace of `directoryReader` on the stack instead of on the heap.

Here's a little refactored version of `p_getfiles`.

```
void p_getfiles_and_directories(char const* basepath,
                                char const* filename, //filename is to ignore
                                std::vector<std::string>& files,
                                std::vector<std::string>& directories)
{
   // This function does not recurse directories.
   // It just returns the file and sub-directories in the given
   // basepath.

   directoryReader dirr(basepath, S_IFREG | S_IFDIR);
   char *tmppath = NULL;
   struct stat st;
   while ((tmppath = dirr.getNext()) != NULL)
   {
      if (strcmp(tmppath, filename) == 0)
         continue;
      if (goodpath(tmppath))
      {
         stat(tmppath, &st);
         if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
         {
            directories.push_back(tmppath);
         }
         else if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
         {
            files.push_back(tmppath);
         }
      }
      free(tmppath);
   }
}

void p_getfiles(char const* basepath, FILE *f, char const* filename) //filename is to ignore
{
   // Get all the files and sub-directories in the given basepath.
   std::vector<std::string> files;
   std::vector<std::string> directories;
   p_getfiles_and_directories(basepath, filename, files, directories);

   // Recurse directories.
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = directories.begin();
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator end = directories.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      if (strcmp((*iter).c_str(), filename) == 0)
         printf("uh oh...\n");
      p_getfiles((*iter).c_str(), f, filename);
   }

   // Process files.
   iter = files.begin();
   end = files.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", (*iter).c_str());
   }
}
```

Comment: That works better for you? I still get the EXACT same issues as before, only now it does honestly look a bit cleaner

Comment: @phyrrus9 yes, it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: What OS are you running it on?

Comment: Could the errors you are seeing be caused by permission issues?

Comment: I am running it as root. Though, since this is intended to run on linux, maybe I should try it on arch.

Comment: You could also try [`perror`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/?kw=perror) to diagnose the cause of failure to open a directory using `opendir`.

Comment: The error is always a NULL pointer error. The message is my own. It looks like a permission issue but it can't be.

Comment: OK, this works perfectly on linux! My issue is, now I get a "*** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x08f70780 ***" message. Is this because of a possibly too small buffer somewhere?

Comment: That aside, it still seems to fail on longer runs. Like, /home, /tmp, etc all work fine, but /usr does not, weird. Is there a limit on stat calls?

Comment: I am seeing a different error on my linux machine. "Unable to open directory: Too many open files". There are symbolic links that are aparently cyclic, which make the directories long and the depth of recursion too deep.

Comment: THAT MESSAGE MAKES SO MUCH MORE SENSE! OK, so I need to find a way to check if it is a symbolic link then, which shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: stat() does not follow symbolic links. And I only have 1 fopen call in the whole thing.

Comment: std::vector<std::string>::iterator dear god no.